# Activate external swap with plug&play

Tags: fstab, external-hdd

I have a flash drive that's completely formatted as swap for use with my LiveUSB system.

It's listed in `/etc/fstab` and not having it present during boot is problematic, as it adds 90 seconds of boot time artificially.

How can I get it to automatically enable swap when I plug it in without having an fstab entry?

Comment: Swap in a USB drive, isn't it terribly slow? Are you sure you really need swap? AFAIK, the live session doesn't use swap by default if there's no swap partition available and automatically enables swapon in the presence of any swap partition already in the system.

Comment: I am very sure I need swap... Also, it's meant to run like a full-fledged system wherever I go. The lag doesn't matter TOO much... (It kind of does, but there are definitely times where it doesn't bother me.)

Comment: Your prerogative of course. Again, AFAIK it should enable swap whenever it detects a swap partition without having it in the fstab. Being in an USB may or may not make a difference. You better wait for answers from the experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, you really can't... But this is a good enough workaround because most of you don't have potatoes. Appending `x-systemd.device-timeout=1` to whatever options you have will make the system wait 1 second before deciding not to mount it and continue on ASAP.

```
<file system>                             <mount point>   <type>  <options>                        <dump>  <pass>
UUID=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 none            swap    sw,x-systemd.device-timeout=1         0       0
```

For some reason it'll mount your device but say it hasn't found it in time when you boot up. AFAIK only happens on Lubuntu 16.04.